# SQL DATE not generating correct result with NOW() or CURRENT_DATE()

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `ec_assessment_item` 
WHERE `ec_assessment_due_date` <= NOW()
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `ec_assessment_item` 
WHERE `ec_assessment_due_date` <= CURRENT_DATE()
```

I want to shows all the data are before due date, and i tested few method including NOW() and CURRENT_DATE() but it always who empty result.

Expected Result should be id: 2 and 3.

[image]

Comment: 31/03/17 is not less than NOW ... did you mean to query _added_date ?

Comment: Unless you live in the future these results are correct

Comment: Your logic has nothing to do with the data.  Please explain what the logic is.  (As I write this, it is 2017-03-28, so none of the assessments are before the current date).

Comment: Unless your are a time traveller from the future, all your dates in `ec_assessment_due_date` are in the future and thus are greater than the current date.

Comment: I want to shows those result are before due date that's why i'm using <=NOW()

Comment: If a due date is earlier (`<`) than now, then we are already **past** the due date.

Comment: I am going to ask a silly question: Sorry: What is your system date set to?

Answer (score 0):

For NOW and CURRENTDATE This are some output example

NOW() : 2017-03-28 14:27:45
CURRENTDATE() :  2017-03-28

NOW() is datetime format (Y-m-d H:m:s)

CURDATE or CURRENTDATE is date format (Y-m-d)

You can run this script `SELECT NOW(),CURRENT_DATE() ;`

This should work. I tested on my side and it works

```
SELECT * FROM ec_assessment_item WHERE ec_assessment_due_date < CURRENT_DATE() ;
```

Sign of strict inferiority to mean before

Also Current Date is 2017-03-28 so the output should be empty as you said before today

Add to the table another row with ec_assessment_due_date = 2017-03-27. The result wont be empty anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `ec_assessment_item` 
WHERE `ec_assessment_due_date` <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE()` is a Synonyms for `CURDATE()` i.e. they are the same function